# Passing object and rows of object to MVC controller via Json/Ajax always returns null values

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

[Please see the attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaHAA.png) I was not able to figure out why all the values of objects being passed to the controller always shows null.   What am I missing here?   Thanks in advance!!

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveOrder(Order order, List<Item> items)
{ 
    //do something here;
    return Json("OK");
}
```

View

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnsave").on('click', function () {
            var url = '@Url.Action("SaveOrder", "Employee")';
            var data1 = { CustomerName: 'MS' };
            var data2 = [{ ItemName: "Laptop", Quantity: 5 },
                         { ItemName: "Desktop", Quantity : 25}];

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                data: { order:data1, items: data2 },
                datatype: "json",
                ContentType: "application/json",
                cache: false,
                success: function (resp) {
                    alert('Success' + resp);
                },
                error: function (resp) {
                    alert("Something Went Wrong" + resp);
                }
            })
        })
    })
</script>
```

Class

```
public class Item 
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{   
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yjmU.png)

Comment: It needs to be `data: JSON.stringify({ order:data1, items: data2 }),`

Comment: Have you checked your model state. This can happen when controller can't map the request body to action arguments. In such cases model state is invalid. Here's the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api) to the documentation

Comment: @sunilsachdeva, It has nothing to do with `ModelState`

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint to make sure the method is actually being executed?

Comment: Also, post a sample of objects data1 and data2.

Comment: Is posting multiple objects to a `HttpPost` method valid?

Comment: You can try another way: Create a container with `Order` and `List<Item>` as properties. Then make that the parameter of  `SaveOrder`.

Comment: adiga, I have added the image.   Posting seems to be valid, just that the values are all null.

Comment: Stephen, I tried stringify (exactly what you suggested but it didn't work.   The controller can't even recognize it is an array of object.  It just treated the whole thing as null.

Comment: Adiga, yes the modelstate returns true.

Comment: @VCheng did you try adding a container and check? (btw, you have to "@user" while replying to comments, otherwise they don't get notification of your reply)

Comment: Please post a sample of objects being sent in Ajax (data1 and data2).